# How to use shared libraries for node_modules in separate containers?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I have three containers running the same NodeJS app, and use NPM to manage each of `libary(node_modules)`.

So far, My solution is that I run `npm install` in `HOST`, and mount the `node_modules` folder for all containers.

Are there better ways to manage it?